# Stop Caching Redirect in NextJS

Tags: next.js

I want to redirect an user to an Error page if I don't find a code `query` param

```js
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

export default function Home(props){
  const router = useRouter();
  useEffect(() =>  {
    if(!props.code){
      console.log('No code found');
      router.push('/error');
    }
  });
  // call an api passing the code
    return (
      <>
        <div>Something</div>
      </>
    )
}

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  context.res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'No-Cache');

  return {
    props: { code: context.query.code || null }
  }
}
```

If an user come to this page with the url `localhost:3000/` it should be redirected to `localhost:3000/error`, but if the user come with a specific query param `localhost:3000/?code=1234` the user must not be redirected.

The problem is when I test this component going to the URL without the `code` param, I'm correctly redirect to the error page (`localhost:3000/error`), but after this, if I enter the url `localhost:3000/?code=1234`, I'm also redirect to the error page.

When I try this in an anonymous window, I'm correctly redirected when going to `localhost:3000/?code=1234` after gone to `localhost:3000/` (and then to the error page)

How can I stop this behaivour?

Comment: this helps you? https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/11281

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that your `useEffect` code should run only once when the component is mounted in the browser.

```js
  useEffect(() =>  {
    if(!props.code){
      console.log('No code found');
      router.push('/error');
    }
  },[]);
```

Or alternatively, you could redirect immediately inside `getServerSideProps`

```js
export const getServerSideProps = async (context) => {
  const { res } =  context;
  // if there is no code do the redirect
  res.writeHead(301, { location: "https://google.com" } );
  res.end();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using `getServerSideProps` and have access to the query params there, you can redirect on the server-side directly and avoid having to even mount the `Home` component.

```js
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
    if (!context.query.code) {
        return {
            redirect: {
                destination: '/error',
                permanent: false
            }
        }
    }

    return {
        props: { code: context.query.code }
    }
}
```